# Error when inserting a PDF page into a Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, pdfpages

I'm using `pdfpages` to insert a page from a pdf file into my Beamer presentation, but the result is a completely empty page. Here is smaller version of the file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xypdf}
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{everyshi} 
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={61}]{IA_Residential_Full_FINAL.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Not sure if it matters, I'm using MikTeX with pdfLaTeX. I've searched the web and haven't been able to figure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Martin. Using your code inserts the pdf page, but only the graphics on the page appear, the text is removed. I am having the same problem with my .eps files when I try to insert graphs. Any thoughts?

Comment: @SteveP: I was under the impression that you wanted only the PDF over the full slide without any text. You don't have any text in your example. I will update my example.

Comment: Also @SteveP: put an @ before my name so that I get a notification of the new comment. The first name is enough.

Comment: @Martin: Sorry, I'm not being clear. I do want only the pdf over the full slide. The pdf page I want to insert contains a graph with accompanying text (e.g. legend, etc.). This text is being stripped out of the pdf page when it is inserted into the latex-created pdf. Turns out it is a problem with my miktex installation, the text appears the first time I compile after starting miktex, but not after. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveP: Mmmm, funny. Maybe try to update or reinstall MikTeX and tell us if it's working then.

Comment: @martin: Just reinstalled and still have the problem - pdfs look fine the first time it compiles, then the text disappears each time after that. Not a bog deal, just means I need to shut it down and restart when I want to save the final version. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SteveP: I'm sorry I still can't fully follow you. AFAIK there is nothing to shutdown and restart on the LaTeX compiler. Maybe you mean the editor you use or the PDF viewer. See diabonas answer, it looks good and might help you.

Answer (score 36):

The [beamer user guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (p.19) provides a solution:

> Commands like `\includepdf` only work
>   outside frames as they produce pages
>   “by themselves.” You may also wish to
>   say
>
> `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}`
>
> when you use such a
>   command since the background (even a
>   white background) will otherwise be
>   printed over the image you try to
>   include.

So the code would be:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pdfpages} 

\begin{document}
{
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
    \includepdf[pages={61}]{IA_Residential_Full_FINAL.pdf}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21):

Don't use `pdfpages` in `beamer`. AFAIK they are not compatible. Include the PDF page using `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package like shown below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{xypdf}
%\usepackage{eso-pic} 
%\usepackage{everyshi} 
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}
\frame[plain]{\includegraphics[page=61,width=\textwidth]{yourfile.pdf}}
\end{document}
```

You should put all material inside a `frame` macro or environment. The `plain` option will remove most of the material like header and footer.

---

The above code is for PDF images spanning the full slide. If you simply want to 
insert an image on a normal slide with some text, then you should use it like this.
Note that the `width=.6\textwidth` makes the image width 60% of the text width (the frame or page width minus margins). Simply adjust the factor to your wishes. There is also `height` and `\textheight`, but the latter includes the slide title and subtitle which makes finding the correct value a little more difficult.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
      Some text before

      \includegraphics[page=61,width=.6\textwidth]{yourfile.pdf}

      some text afterwards
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked for me, although the `width=\textwidth` didn't span the full slide.  There must be another setting for that...

Comment: @Joe Corneli The following command will span the full slide: `\includepdf[pages=61,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{yourfile.pdf}`

Comment: @VladimirS. -- thanks, this works better but I get a white bar on the left margin