# How to include existing PDF slides into my Beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, pdf

Is there a way to incorporate some slides into an existing slide into my Beamer presentation?

Say, I want to put slide 2 in file A (a Beamer PDF file) into my Beamer presentation, can this be done?

PS: `file A` is a PDF and does not have bounding box.

Comment: Every PDF has a bounding box - otherwise it would be broken.

Comment: Formally speaking, a PDF has no "bounding box". Available boxes with their full names are: `/MediaBox`, `/CropBox`, `/BleedBox`, `/ArtBox` and `/TrimBox`. The only *required* box info that must be present in a PDF file is the `/MediaBox`. If undefined, the other boxes should be assumed by PDF-processing software to have the same values as the `/MediaBox`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with using very basic solution.

how to incorparate slides in existing multi-page pdf (say file A) into my beamer?

> @windows, cutepdf to print many one-slide pdfs B from file A.
>
> @ubuntu, pdftops to create per-slide eps C for each pdf B.
>
> then, load those eps C in latex.

Comment: EPS? Why don't you create PDFs?

Comment: If you want to cut and paste together pages from multiple pages, pdftk is usually a sensible option. (More sensible than using pdftops in any case).

Comment: Among all the answers, this is considered the worst. Why not use the `pdfpages` package and the `\includepdf` command?

Answer (score 76):

To import a slide from another `beamer` presentation as a "picture", you can use [`pdfpages`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). You'll have to `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}`  [as explained in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11501/3323) because only a white frame will be shown otherwise:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Content
\end{frame}
{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\includepdf[pages=3]{filea.pdf}
}
\end{document}
```

---

However, if you use head- or footlines or even a different theme in your existing presentation, this will probably not fit snugly. In this case, a better solution would be to actually import the source code of the existing presentation, which can be done using the [`docmute`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/docmute) package in combination with the `\againframe` command:

Suppose this is your existing presentation `filea.tex`: You need to give the slides you want to import a name using the `label` option of the frame environment, like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=myframe]
Frame to be included
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Then you can use this code in your new presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{docmute}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\loadpresentation}[1]{{\beamer@inlecturefalse\input{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\loadpresentation{filea.tex}
\begin{frame}
  The new presentation
\end{frame}
\againframe{myframe}
\end{document}
```

Issuing `\loadpresentation{filea.tex}` imports the frames from your existing presentation without displaying them. You can insert them wherever  needed using `\againframe` with the label you chose in `filea.tex`. The command `\loadpresentation` should be used someplace *after* `\begin{document}` (but before you actually include a frame from this presentation, of course).

This works roughly the same as if you'd actually copy the source code of the frame from the existing presentation, so things like overlays etc. are taken over.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to put a "thumbnail" of some target [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) PDF `fileA` in your source, you can use

```
\includegraphics[page=<n>,width=<len>]{fileA}
```

where `<n>` is the absolute page number of the slide in `fileA.pdf`, and `<len>` is the width of the imported page. You can also scale this using the other options provided by [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). `beamer` loads `graphicx` by default, so the functionality is already available.

If you want to put a "full page" of some target `beamer` PDF `fileA` in your source, you can use

```
\begin{frame}
\vspace*{-1pt}
\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[page=<n>,width=\paperwidth]{fileA}}
\end{frame}
```

where `<n>` is the absolute page number of the slide in `fileA`. The slide is stretched to fit `\paperwidth` so should overlay the source presentation completely.

The vertical correction (`1pt`) is needed to maintain a consistent display from one slide to the next.

Comment: this comes with a bounding box error, it seems the fileA does not have bounding box.

Comment: @Richard: Not in my minimal testing. You should post two minimal examples as part of your question. One for `fileA` (if created using LaTeX) and one for you main document.

Comment: the main doc is a beamer presentation created in latex, and `file A` is a pdf generated in Mac.

Comment: The amount of vspace needs to be tweaked for the specific style being used, but this works flawlessly for me with PDFs generated by other software such as Keynote or PowerPoint.

Comment: +1: Used this approach many times today (for the first time). *Can you explain the reasoning behind `\vspace*{-1pt}` and `\makebox[\linewidth]`? And how is the vertical position determined?*

Comment: @Werner, Is there a way to specify more than one page e.g. if the target has more than 1 page?

Comment: @chandresh: Just include separate images, one from each of the pages you're after.

Comment: This is what I did as a workaround. I thought there might be a scalable way in case someone wants to include large number of pdf pages.

Comment: @chandresh: You can include page ranges using [`pdfpages`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages), but they would be included as-is (sleeved between your other document pages). Using `\includegraphics` you can select the page you want to include and resize it to fit where you want it.

Comment: @Werner. Thanks for the suggestion. I did this. `{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\includepdf[pages={1-4}, frame=true]{haar-1-4.pdf}
}
` to include multiple pages in beamer. It indeed spills over the entire page. I am not sure what you mean about `\includegraphics` resizing thing.

Comment: @chandresh: When you use `\includegraphics`, the image (or page) is imported as an object that you can `\resizebox` as you like. For example, `\resizebox{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{\includegraphics[page=1]{haar-1-4.pdf}\includegraphics[page=2]{haar-1-4.pdf}\includegraphics[page=3]{haar-1-4.pdf}\includegraphics[page=4]{haar-1-4.pdf}}` to have 4 pages sized to your dimensions. In general, it allows you to include "thumbnails" of pages and place it wherever you want. If you use `\includepdf`, adjusting the layout of the imported pages is not always easy.

Comment: You can also change the size of the included PDF using `scale`: `\includegraphics[scale=.5]{someDir/myPdf}`