# Frame label in the right top corner of slide?

Tags: beamer, labels

How can I access the frame label inside the frame?

I have a big master file with hundreds of slides and I would like to use slides from it in my other presentations using method described in 
[how to include existing pdf slides into my beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57441/how-to-include-existing-pdf-slides-into-my-beamer). However, to easier track the slides in master file I would like to print the frame label on top of everything in the top right corner of the frame. I have not succeeded to find answer to my problem in this forum.

The example below is my attempt on working example but it puts just text 'frame-label' where I would like to see the real frame label.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(0\textwidth,0cm)%
        \tiny \textcolor{gray}{slide:frame-label}%
\end{textblock*}%
}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%% Frame 1
\begin{frame}[label=738473]{Frame1 title}
frame1 text
\end{frame}

%%%%%%% Frame 2
\begin{frame}[label=847242]{Frame2 title}
frame2 text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). If you want to print the frame label for the master file you should first specify which is the Beamer theme adopted.

Comment: Would some label descriptor macro be allowed in the frmetitle, or does it have to come from the frame's label?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand this. To make as little error as possible I imagine that I would like to have something like in my MWE, i.e. the frame label has to be entered only once, preferentially in the standard way. @TomBombadil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is not very robust but it works with your example (with a first frame without label).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\insertlabelofcurrentframe{%
  \ifx\beamer@againname\@undefined%
  no label%
  \else%
  \beamer@againname%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
  \begin{textblock*}{3cm}(0\textwidth,0cm)%
    \tiny \textcolor{gray}{\insertlabelofcurrentframe}%
  \end{textblock*}%
}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%% Frame 0
\begin{frame}{No label...}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%% Frame 1
\begin{frame}[label=738473]{Frame1 title}
frame1 text
\end{frame}

%%%%%%% Frame 2
\begin{frame}[label=847242]{Frame2 title}
frame2 text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```