# Have very large table needing automatic division across multiple beamer frames and multi column within each frame. Package suggestion?

Tags: tables, beamer, multicolumn

I have very large data tables that I would like to present within beamer frames.
I need a package that will divide the table into several columns within a frame and to
multiple frames.

xtab package manages to divide across multiple frames. But does not work with multicol package.

If I divide the table to multiple sub-tables, tabularx, and multicol combination works but requires a lot of labor. In addition, the table width that I work with is not necessarily constant due to the varying string length of its content, hence I also need to scale each and every one of them etc...

The tables that I am trying to put to the presentation are automatically generated and I have a lot of them, so doing it manually is NOT an option.

Hence, I am trying to find a table package that works with beamer frames and able to divide a very long table across multiple columns within a frame and across as many frames as need with proper size scaling.

It is a long wish list but just trying. Any advise?

Comment: You may try using a breakable tcolorbox outside of a frame, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509208. (I am not sure, though, if the audience will be pleasantly surprised by having a presentation containing an automatically generated table running over several slides.)

Comment: Think carefully if the presentation of huge amounts of tabular data really makes sense in a presentation context. Are the real values significant for the audience or could a matrix of colors achieve the same result? (I'm thinking of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418604/color-cells-of-a-matrix-with-rgb)

Comment: One option could be split the endless table in onecolumn article document and then include the PDF in Beamer (see  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57441/how-to-include-existing-pdf-slides-into-my-beamer-presentation). But this question smell to XY problem. Probably it will be better change the automatic method to produce smaller tables. If you show some fake example data, explaining how you convert this data automatically in a long table, maybe someone could suggest  alternative ways.

Comment: This presentation is for project documentation rather than presentation. So yes, it would be very boring to present these tables to an audience. But colleagues prefer ppt format for documentation and I need to add all the information (because it is documentation). I am checking what you guys are suggesting. Thank you for the reply.