# Beamer uploads graph but not labels

Tags: beamer, graphics

I'm new to `beamer` and am trying to make a basic presentation.  I have some graphs (generated in STATA) that I want to upload to my presentation.  The graphics are pdfs. Beamer generates a presentation including the graphic, but omits my labels and tick lines.  How can I upload my graphs with labels?

```
\begin{frame} {inserting a graphic}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=3in]{graph.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Do you mean the numbering part? If that is the case then it is normal as referencing within beamer, or as it is, in a presentation is a little awkward.

Comment: When I upload the graph my axis labels are not included.

Comment: @Katey -- try reducing the value of height=3in, or use scale=0.5 instead.

Comment: @Jesse thanks for the suggestion.  I tried both options and am still running into the same issue

Comment: @Katey -- found more info here. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11501/34618

Comment: Unrelated: there's no need to put your graph in a `figure` environment in Beamer, unless you want to `\caption` the graph.

Comment: @Jesse thanks for sending that my way.  I tried some of the suggestions and code on that page but am still running into the same problem.  My graphs upload into the presentation but any labeling does not come with it.  Perhaps I'll try saving my graph in a different file format to see if that makes a difference

Comment: Are you sure the labels exist in the pdf file you include? Maybe STATA exported without labels and ticks.