# How to disable Beamer's theming on last page?

Tags: beamer, themes, forms, adobe, debian

I want to disable beamer's theming and `\usetheme` effect on the last page. 
Expected output is for the official form view similarly as in Fig. 1. 
I am gathering input from all other pages, and lastly, showing the result on the last page as A4 without any presentation formats from `\usetheme`.

Expected output: pages 1-2 presentation presentation theme, but last page A4 form without effect of `\usetheme`

Fig. 1 Example form

[image]

Code motivated by comments and their linked thread answers

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}    
\usetheme{Berkeley} 
\logo{
%% llx lly urx ury
\includegraphics[trim=8cm 2cm 11cm 2cm,clip, height=\headheight, width=\headheight]{example-image}
}

%\usepackage{hyperref} % Not needed!
\begin{document}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384801/13173

% Take data input from Page 1
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{muuttujat}
\section{1. taidot} 

\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \ChoiceMenu[name=football,radio,default=-0]{Do you play football?}{Much (2)=2,Little (1)=1,Not at all (0)=0}
\item \ChoiceMenu[name=ice-hockey,radio,default=-0]{Do you play ice-hockey?}{Much (2)=2,Little (1)=1,Not at all (0)=0}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}
\end{frame}

% Take data input from Page 2
\begin{frame}
\section{2. lorem}

\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \ChoiceMenu[name=soccer,radio,default=-0]{Do you play football?}{Much (2)=2,Little (1)=1,Not at all (0)=0}
\item \ChoiceMenu[name=earth-hockey,radio,default=-0]{Do you play ice-hockey?}{Much (2)=2,Little (1)=1,Not at all (0)=0}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}
\end{frame}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385265/13173
\pdfpagewidth 21cm
\pdfpageheight 29.7cm

% Show summary here from Page 1 and 2
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vskip1cm
\begin{minipage}{19cm}
    \frametitle{START}
    \section{Summary}
    \begin{Form}
    \TextField[readonly=true,value=0,calculate={event.value=this.getField("football").value+this.getField("ice-hockey").value+this.getField("soccer").value+this.getField("earth-hockey").value;}]{Summary score:}
\end{Form}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
\pdfpagewidth \beamer@paperwidth
\pdfpageheight \beamer@paperheight
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Output: as expected in paper style but the style control tools are still there in Fig. 4

Fig. 4 Control tools wrongly visible on the last page

[image]

OS: Debian 9
TeXLive: 2017
PDF viewer: Adobe `acroread` installed like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309313/how-to-install-adobe-reader-enu-in-64-bit-debian-8-5/309332#309332)

Comment: Maybe this [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11501/82389) (using the pdfpages package) will do the trick?

Comment: Oh sorry, it looks like I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to insert a pdf (the form given) into a beamer presentation. Instead you just want to disable beamer's theming on a given slide, I think?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you want. But, would `\begin{frame}[plain]` do?

Comment: Also, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134876/105447. If I understood well, samcarter's answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Léo, I think it would be easier to try to answer if you stated more clearly from the start what you are trying to do. It is still not clear if the content of your last slide, as provided in your code, is circumstantial or not. For example, one of the answers in David's suggested link gives the result which apparently you want by simply including a file (as your initial form) _without_ a frame. But it is not clear.

Comment: @gusbrs Please, see the body of the minimal approach.

Comment: Offtopic: Never use things like `\section` inside a frame, but always outside.

Comment: @samcarter, well remembered, I corrected my answer accordingly. BTW, credit is all yours here!

Comment: @gusbrs You're welcome! Good to hear it seemed useful for 1 person :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the iteration in the comments, I'll try to answer, even though I'm still not clear on what the OP wants. If I understood correctly, you could try the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}    
\usetheme{Berkeley} 

\begin{document}

% Take data input from Page 1
\section{1. taidot} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{muuttujat}   
\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \ChoiceMenu[name=football,radio,default=-0]{Do you play football?}{Much (2)=2,Little (1)=1,Not at all (0)=0}
\item \ChoiceMenu[name=ice-hockey,radio,default=-0]{Do you play ice-hockey?}{Much (2)=2,Little (1)=1,Not at all (0)=0}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}
\end{frame}

% Take data input from Page 2
\section{2. lorem}
\begin{frame}
\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \ChoiceMenu[name=soccer,radio,default=-0]{Do you play football?}{Much (2)=2,Little (1)=1,Not at all (0)=0}
\item \ChoiceMenu[name=earth-hockey,radio,default=-0]{Do you play ice-hockey?}{Much (2)=2,Little (1)=1,Not at all (0)=0}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}
\end{frame}

\begingroup
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385265/13173
\pdfpagewidth 21cm
\pdfpageheight 29.7cm

% Show summary here from Page 1 and 2
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vskip1cm
\begin{minipage}{19cm}
    \frametitle{START}
    \section{Summary}
    \begin{Form}
    \TextField[readonly=true,value=0,calculate={event.value=this.getField("football").value+this.getField("ice-hockey").value+this.getField("soccer").value+this.getField("earth-hockey").value;}]{Summary score:}
\end{Form}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

% these below eventually are not needed, if this is the last slide of your document

\makeatletter
\pdfpagewidth \beamer@paperwidth
\pdfpageheight \beamer@paperheight
\makeatother
\endgroup    

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the only thing that is needed is `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` to remove navigation symbols. I think `\begingroup ... \endgroup` is not needed at all. What do you think?

Comment: I was trying to make changes local, but I guess you are correct, if this one is indeed the last slide. In general, it would be more prudent, and I thing there's no harm in leaving it. So, apart from this, that was indeed what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: I mean that if you use `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` if you include a new frame after `\endgroup`, the controls would return to defaults, because `\setbeamertemplate` would thus affect only what's within the group.

Comment: Those are to restore `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` to beamer's defaults, as in samcarter's answer. I'm not sure they are strictly necessary here with the use of the group, though. You can try things out a bit.

Comment: I extend the case here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385431/13173 with affecting the margins of the plain page. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really, @LéoLéopoldHertz준영. But I think you should mention there that that is a follow up question from this one. And state clearly what is the difference of what you are trying to achieve, which was not covered here.